# How do I Iterate through an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<p v-for="quest in exam.questions" :key="quest">{{quest.text}}</p>
```

```
data() {
    return {
        message: "QUESTION DIPLAYS HERE",
        name: "Ayoola",
        exam: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "",
            ref: "",
            duration: 24000,
            type: "cbt",
            format: {
                type: "random",
                total: 20,
            },
            description: "In this exam do not cheat",
            questions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "who is this"
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "code": "A",
                        "text": "Man was created in God's image",
                        "is_correct": true,
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "B",
                        "text": "Man was created to look like angels",
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "C",
                        "text": "Man created himself",
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "D",
                        "text": "Man was not created and cannot be destroyed",
                    },
                ]
            ]
        }],
```

Comment: I want to access each properties inside questions: like accessing id, text, options etc. how do I do that?

Comment: Your `questions` array doesn't work because arrays can't have properties

Comment: Thanks, so what do you suggest it `questions` be written? I want every question to have and id, text, options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Uncaught SyntaxError

First, your data object is `not valid` (Inspect your code).

> "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'",

[image]

```js
/* Throw error:
"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'",
*/
var error = [
  {
    name: "valid"
  },
  name: "not valid"  
]

/* correct code */
var valid = [
  {
    name: "valid"
  },
  {
    name: "valid two"
  }
]
```

#### Nested v-for

Next, you not going correctly throw the nested object (Try to print one item manually before you using v-for).

- `exam.questions[0].text` (Not correct).
- Should be: `exam.questions[0].options[0].text`

The best idea is to follow this basic "Hello World" example and edit your code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return{
      msg: "world",
      exam: {
        name: "Exam name",
        questions: [
          {
            id: 10,
            title: 'The capital of France?',
            "options": [
              {
                "code": "A",
                "text": "Paris",
                "is_correct": true,
              },
              {
                "code": "B",
                "text": "Lyon",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 11,
            title: 'The capital of Italy?',
            "options": [
              {
                "code": "A",
                "text": "Verona",
                "is_correct": true,
              },
              {
                "code": "B",
                "text": "Roma",
                "is_correct": true
              }
            ]
          },

        ]
      }
    }
  }  
})
```

```html
<main id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="question in exam.questions" :key="question.id">
      <h3>{{ question.title }}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="option in question.options" :key="option.code">
          {{ option.text }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Related docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Great :) Mark as an answer to close this Q :)

Comment: and one more thing Ezra, how do I go about this? `<div class="inputGroup">
              <input id="radio_id" name="radio" type="radio" class="inputGroup_radio" v-model="picked"/>
              <label for="radio_id" class="inputGroup_label">{{ option.text }}</label>
            </div>` I want the radio id and the label(for) be dynamic

Comment: Maybe open separate Q related to this issue (Hard to answer/explain by comment). 
Again add minimal working code to your Q (Like my snippet).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about object, but in your example you have array with parent and child objects. If `exam` needs to be an array then solution is:

```
v-for="quest in exam[0].questions"
```

Comment: put `options` insige of `questions` object

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate such like that. (On COMPUTED you can in the future apply filter for instance)

```
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="quest in test_data" :key="quest.id">
    {{quest.id}} <br>
    {{quest.text}}
  </li>
</ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return{
        exam: 
         { questions: [ 
           { id:1,
            text:"who is this",
            options:[
                {
                    "code": "A",
                    "text": "Man was created in God's image",
                    "is_correct": true,
                },
                {
                    "code": "B",
                    "text": "Man was created to look like angels",
                }
            ]
          }
      
          ] }
    
    }
  },
  computed: {
        test_data() {
            return this.exam.questions;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify which exam you want to loop through or you can make a v-for above the form if you want to have multiple exam elements
For iterating through the array simple you can put a for loop inside the question loop and iterate through each option and print it out

Here is how I implemented it :

```
<form>
        <div v-for="quest in exam[0].questions" :key="quest.id">
            <p>{{ quest.text }}</p>
            <label v-for="(option, index) in quest.options" :key="index" :for="'answer'+quest.id+index">
                <input type="radio" :name="'answer'+quest.id" :id="'answer'+quest.id+index">
                {{ option.text }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>

data() {
    return {
        message: "QUESTION DIPLAYS HERE",
        name: "Ayoola",
        exam: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "",
                ref: "",
                duration: 24000,
                type: "cbt",
                format: {
                    type: "random",
                    total: 20
                },
                description: "In this exam do not cheat",
                questions: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        text: "who is this",
                        options: [
                            {
                                code: "A",
                                text: "Man was created in God's image",
                                is_correct: true
                            },
                            {
                                code: "B",
                                text: "Man was created to look like angels"
                            },
                            {
                                code: "C",
                                text: "Man created himself"
                            },
                            {
                                code: "D",
                                text:
                                    "Man was not created and cannot be destroyed"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        text: "who is this",
                        options: [
                            {
                                code: "A",
                                text: "Man was created in God's image",
                                is_correct: true
                            },
                            {
                                code: "B",
                                text: "Man was created to look like angels"
                            },
                            {
                                code: "C",
                                text: "Man created himself"
                            },
                            {
                                code: "D",
                                text:
                                    "Man was not created and cannot be destroyed"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: hello Yazan I your answer would have worked perfectly for me but it's still not displaying, I guess its because it has `exam[0].questions` part.